# MongoDB 2.6.4 query not optimal - takes excessive time to return a result

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, php-mongodb

We are using MongoDB 2.6.4 on an amazon instance. We have a query that is taking an excessive amount of time to return results. NOTE: We are using 10gen php driver but have extracted the raw query for the purpose of troubleshooting the query itself.

```
@db.instant_leads_properties.aggregate(

[
   {
      "$match":{
         "$or":[
            {
               "address":{
                  "$regex":"Louisiana",
                  "$options":"i" 
               }
            },
            {
               "notes":{
                  "$regex":"Louisiana",
                  "$options":"i" 
               }
            },
            {
               "city":"Louisiana" 
            },
            {
               "state":"louisiana" 
            },
            {
               "zip":"71230" 
            }
         ],
         "$and":[
            {
               "featured_expires":{
                  "$gt":{
                     "sec":1407957033,
                     "usec":0
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   {
      "$sort":{
         "listing_date":-1
      }
   },
   {
      "$skip":0
   },
   {
      "$limit":10
   }
]
);
```

If we run the query directly on the mongodb server it takes 20 seconds to return nothing.

The specific piece that seems to be causing the issue is as follows. If this is removed then we get a result back that contains records immediately.

```
"$and":[
   {
      "featured_expires":{
         "$gt":{
            "sec":1407957033,
            "usec":0
         }
      }
   }
]
```

I have created indexes, compound indexes and have configured an amazon ec2 instance using the 10gen optimized mongodb AMI. Neither of these attempts have made a difference. Our db stats are as follows:

```
    {
      "serverUsed": "REMOVED",
      "db": "REMOVED",
      "collections": 10,
      "objects": 4719489,
      "avgObjSize": 1222.960180646676,
      "dataSize": 5.77174712E9,
      "storageSize": 6.340694016E9,
      "numExtents": 49,
      "indexes": 39,
      "indexSize": 6.506763312E9,
      "fileSize": 1.4958985216E10,
      "nsSizeMB": 16,
      "dataFileVersion": {
        "major": 4,
        "minor": 6
      },
      "extentFreeList": {
        "num": 0,
        "totalSize": 0
      },
      "ok": 1.0
    }

The stats for the collection being used (instant_leads_properies) are as follows:

{
  "serverUsed": "REMOVED",
  "ns": "staging.instant_leads_properties",
  "count": 2204568,
  "size": 5.447771456E9,
  "avgObjSize": 2471,
  "storageSize": 5.877628928E9,
  "numExtents": 21,
  "nindexes": 31,
  "lastExtentSize": 1532088320,
  "paddingFactor": 1.0040000000383855,
  "systemFlags": 0,
  "userFlags": 1,
  "totalIndexSize": 6.4251096E9,
  "indexSizes": {
    "_id_": 71564528,
    "listing_key_1": 120252608,
    "state_1_property_type_1_city_1_listing_date_1": 199379936,
    "state_1_property_type_1_zip_1_listing_date_1": 184082640,
    "state_1_property_type_1_county_1_listing_date_1": 192258640,
    "asking_price_1": 103418224,
    "living_area_1": 95144112,
    "living_area_1_asking_price_1": 117047616,
    "listing_date_1_living_area_1_asking_price_1": 137340448,
    "zip_1_living_area_1_asking_price_1": 142286928,
    "longitude_1_latitude_1": 98978656,
    "rem_id_1_created_at_-1": 57837024,
    "rem_id_1_listing_date_-1": 54501216,
    "point_2dsphere": 37740416,
    "property_type_1": 66650752,
    "address_1": 78890224,
    "notes_1": 861096320,
    "city_1": 60543280,
    "state_1": 59096128,
    "zip_1": 51582384,
    "property_type_1_featured_expired_1": 69046320,
    "property_type_1_featured_expires_1": 69054496,
    "city_1_state_1_zip_1": 100303168,
    "address_1_city_1_state_1_zip_1": 144159232,
    "address_1_city_1_state_1_zip_1_featured_expires_1": 146423984,
    "latitude_1": 112501760,
    "notes_text": 2.717898624E9,
    "featured_expires_1": 37724064,
    "sec_1": 37724064,
    "usec_1": 37724064,
    "address_1_city_1_state_1_zip_1_featured_expires_1_listing_date_-1": 162857744
  },
  "ok": 1.0
}
```

and the list of indexes for this collection:

```
{ "v" : 1 , "key" : { "_id" : 1} , "ns" : "staging.instant_leads_properties" , "name" : "_id_"}
{ "v" : 1 , "key" : { "listing_key" : 1} , "unique" : true , "ns" : "staging.instant_leads_properties" , "background" : true , "name" : "listing_key_1"}
{ "v" : 1 , "key" : { "state" : 1 , "property_type" : 1 , "city" : 1 , "listing_date" : 1} , "ns" : "staging.instant_leads_properties" , "background" : true , "name" : "state_1_property_type_1_city_1_listing_date_1"}
{ "v" : 1 , "key" : { "state" : 1 , "property_type" : 1 , "zip" : 1 , "listing_date" : 1} , "ns" : "staging.instant_leads_properties" , "background" : true , "name" : "state_1_property_type_1_zip_1_listing_date_1"}
{ "v" : 1 , "key" : { "state" : 1 , "property_type" : 1 , "county" : 1 , "listing_date" : 1} , "ns" : "staging.instant_leads_properties" , "background" : true , "name" : "state_1_property_type_1_county_1_listing_date_1"}
{ "v" : 1 , "key" : { "asking_price" : 1} , "ns" : "staging.instant_leads_properties" , "name" : "asking_price_1" , "background" : true}
{ "v" : 1 , "key" : { "living_area" : 1} , "ns" : "staging.instant_leads_properties" , "name" : "living_area_1" , "background" : true}
{ "v" : 1 , "key" : { "living_area" : 1 , "asking_price" : 1} , "ns" : "staging.instant_leads_properties" , "name" : "living_area_1_asking_price_1" , "background" : true}
{ "v" : 1 , "key" : { "listing_date" : 1 , "living_area" : 1 , "asking_price" : 1} , "ns" : "staging.instant_leads_properties" , "name" : "listing_date_1_living_area_1_asking_price_1" , "background" : true}
{ "v" : 1 , "key" : { "zip" : 1 , "living_area" : 1 , "asking_price" : 1} , "ns" : "staging.instant_leads_properties" , "name" : "zip_1_living_area_1_asking_price_1" , "background" : true}
{ "v" : 1 , "key" : { "longitude" : 1.0 , "latitude" : 1.0} , "ns" : "staging.instant_leads_properties" , "name" : "longitude_1_latitude_1"}
{ "v" : 1 , "key" : { "rem_id" : 1.0 , "created_at" : -1.0} , "ns" : "staging.instant_leads_properties" , "name" : "rem_id_1_created_at_-1"}
{ "v" : 1 , "key" : { "rem_id" : 1.0 , "listing_date" : -1.0} , "ns" : "staging.instant_leads_properties" , "name" : "rem_id_1_listing_date_-1"}
{ "v" : 1 , "key" : { "point" : "2dsphere"} , "ns" : "staging.instant_leads_properties" , "name" : "point_2dsphere"}
{ "v" : 1 , "key" : { "property_type" : 1.0} , "ns" : "staging.instant_leads_properties" , "name" : "property_type_1"}
{ "v" : 1 , "key" : { "address" : 1.0} , "ns" : "staging.instant_leads_properties" , "name" : "address_1"}
{ "v" : 1 , "key" : { "notes" : 1.0} , "ns" : "staging.instant_leads_properties" , "name" : "notes_1"}
{ "v" : 1 , "key" : { "city" : 1.0} , "ns" : "staging.instant_leads_properties" , "name" : "city_1"}
{ "v" : 1 , "key" : { "state" : 1.0} , "ns" : "staging.instant_leads_properties" , "name" : "state_1"}
{ "v" : 1 , "key" : { "zip" : 1.0} , "ns" : "staging.instant_leads_properties" , "name" : "zip_1"}
{ "v" : 1 , "key" : { "property_type" : 1.0 , "featured_expired" : 1.0} , "ns" : "staging.instant_leads_properties" , "name" : "property_type_1_featured_expired_1"}
{ "v" : 1 , "key" : { "property_type" : 1.0 , "featured_expires" : 1.0} , "ns" : "staging.instant_leads_properties" , "name" : "property_type_1_featured_expires_1"}
{ "v" : 1 , "key" : { "city" : 1.0 , "state" : 1.0 , "zip" : 1.0} , "name" : "city_1_state_1_zip_1" , "ns" : "staging.instant_leads_properties"}
{ "v" : 1 , "key" : { "address" : 1.0 , "city" : 1.0 , "state" : 1.0 , "zip" : 1.0} , "name" : "address_1_city_1_state_1_zip_1" , "ns" : "staging.instant_leads_properties"}
{ "v" : 1 , "key" : { "address" : 1.0 , "city" : 1.0 , "state" : 1.0 , "zip" : 1.0 , "featured_expires" : 1.0} , "name" : "address_1_city_1_state_1_zip_1_featured_expires_1" , "ns" : "staging.instant_leads_properties"}
{ "v" : 1 , "key" : { "latitude" : 1.0} , "name" : "latitude_1" , "ns" : "staging.instant_leads_properties" , "background" : true}
{ "v" : 1 , "key" : { "_fts" : "text" , "_ftsx" : 1} , "name" : "notes_text" , "ns" : "staging.instant_leads_properties" , "weights" : { "notes" : 1} , "default_language" : "english" , "language_override" : "language" , "textIndexVersion" : 2}
{ "v" : 1 , "key" : { "featured_expires" : 1.0} , "name" : "featured_expires_1" , "ns" : "staging.instant_leads_properties"}
{ "v" : 1 , "key" : { "sec" : 1.0} , "name" : "sec_1" , "ns" : "staging.instant_leads_properties"}
{ "v" : 1 , "key" : { "usec" : 1.0} , "name" : "usec_1" , "ns" : "staging.instant_leads_properties"}
{ "v" : 1 , "key" : { "address" : 1.0 , "city" : 1.0 , "state" : 1.0 , "zip" : 1.0 , "featured_expires" : 1.0 , "listing_date" : -1.0} , "name" : "address_1_city_1_state_1_zip_1_featured_expires_1_listing_date_-1" , "ns" : "staging.instant_leads_properties"}
```

Please let me know what other information would provide insight.

thanks
Jason

Comment: wow that's HIGHLY Relational data to be storing in a Non-Relational Document store like MongoDb...

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to create an text index over `address`,`notes`,`city` and `state`:

```
db.instant_lead_properties.ensureIndex({address:"text",notes:"text",city:"text", state:"text"})
```

and adjust the match part of your aggregation as follows:

```
[...]
 $match:
 {
   $text: { $search: "Louisiana" },
   "featured_expires": { "$gt": { "sec":1407957033,"usec":0 } }
 }
[...]
```

This way, your are preventing `$or` and `$and` to be chained, which from my experience always has an impact on performance.

Neat features like weighted results come with that, too.

Also, instead of having two separate indices for `sec` and `usec`, a compound index for those two fields might help.

Without a detailed look into MMS monitoring and without knowing the exact configuration of the servers, there is nothing more I can see from here.